# How to Access Browser helper Object Method

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call BHO from Javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474808/call-bho-from-javascript-function)

How to access BHO's method from java script

Comment: You need to *really* clarify your question. As per ["How to Ask" guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), you need to be a lot more specific than this.

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago I have found solution for the same problem, but it was just one-time experiment with BHO, so today it's hardly to remember what to do. But I can give you this piece of code as a starting point to further searching.

```
void CEventSink::Event_NavigateComplete(IDispatch *pDisp, LPOLESTR url)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    IDispatch *pTmpDisp;

    IWebBrowser2 *pFrame;
    hr = pDisp->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowser2, (void **)&pFrame);
    if (FAILED(hr) || !pFrame)
        return;

    hr = pFrame->get_Document(&pTmpDisp);
    if (FAILED(hr) || !pTmpDisp)
        return;

    IHTMLDocument2 *pDocument;
    hr = pTmpDisp->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument2, (void **)&pDocument);
    if (FAILED(hr) || !pDocument)
        return;

    IHTMLWindow2 *pWindow;
    pDocument->get_parentWindow(&pWindow);
    if (FAILED(hr) || !pWindow)
        return;

    IDispatchEx *pDispEx;
    hr = pWindow->QueryInterface(IID_IDispatchEx, (void **)&pDispEx);
    if (FAILED(hr) || !pDispEx)
        return;

    DISPID dispId;
    BSTR name = SysAllocString(_T("someMethod"));
    pDispEx->GetDispID(name, fdexNameEnsure, &dispId);
    SysFreeString(name);
    if (FAILED(hr) || dispId == DISPID_UNKNOWN)
        return;

    hr = this->QueryInterface(IID_IDispatch, (void **)&pTmpDisp);
    if (FAILED(hr) || !pTmpDisp)
        return;

    VARIANT v;
    VariantInit(&v);
    v.vt = VT_DISPATCH;
    v.pdispVal = pTmpDisp;

    DISPID ppid = DISPID_PROPERTYPUT;
    DISPPARAMS p;
    p.rgvarg = &v;
    p.cArgs = 1;
    p.rgdispidNamedArgs = &ppid;
    p.cNamedArgs = 1;

    hr = pDispEx->InvokeEx(dispId, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, 
                           DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT, &p, NULL, NULL, NULL); 
}
```