# ScrollToOptions' behavior: 'smooth' broken in Chrome and Edge v81+

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, browser-api

After testing in BrowserStack, I've concluded that using `scrollTo()` with option parameter `behavior: smooth` does not work in Chrome and Edge since version 81. Version 80 of both Edge and Chrome was working as expected. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScrollToOptions/behavior), it should be working with no asterisk. (unlike Safari)

In popular answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7717572/5988657), using `behavior: smooth` is the recommended way to enable smooth-scrolling in your web application.

Here's a small reproducible:

```html
<html>
<button onclick="goToAnchor('b')">Scroll to B</button>
<div id="a" style="height: 1000px; background-color: blue;">Blue</div>
<div id="b" style="height: 1000px; background-color: red;">Red</div>
<div id="c" style="height: 1000px; background-color: green;">Green</div>

</html>

<script>
  function goToAnchor(anchor) {
    let rect = document.getElementById(anchor).getBoundingClientRect();
    window.scrollTo({
      left: rect.left + window.pageXOffset,
      top: rect.top + window.pageYOffset,
      behavior: 'smooth',
    });
  }
</script>
```

The expected behavior would be that the browser window smoothly interpolate the view down to the red div. It does this properly in all versions of Firefox I've tested. In all of the versions of Chrome since v81, and all versions of Edge since v81, it seems to use the behavior of `behavior: auto` - i.e. it jumps to the div rather than smoothly interpolating the view.

In version 80 of both Edge and Chrome, it behaves just like Firefox, meaning this bug (?) must've been introduced in version 81 - perhaps in the shared Chromium code-base?

I find it *very* unlikely that I am the first person to find this issue, as it has been not been working since April, and must therefore conclude I am doing something wrong. Can someone point towards the error in the code? Or is the Chrome and Edge APIs really broken? Is the behavior hidden behind a feature flag, like in Safari?

Comment: Works in my Chrome 87.0.4280.66 and Edge  87.0.664.60

Comment: On what platform? I've tried it via BrowserStack in Win10, Win7 and Mac, not working in any of those cases for me.

Comment: Win 10 for me... Smooth

Comment: Interesting. Could this have something to do with user preferences?

Comment: W10 x64, Chrome 87.0.4280.88, Edge 87.0.664.60 - Both jump w/o animation to the red div (FF83 works)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe I've found the culprit, and interestingly, it seems it is Firefox that is the odd one out.

In [this StackOverflow thread about detecting RDP connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417883/how-to-detect-from-browser-if-user-is-running-in-remote-desktop-session), the [current top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62245171/5988657) says:

> You can use the following media query:
>
> ```
> @media screen and (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) { . . . }
> ```

The `prefers-reduced-motion` part is interesting. It seems in my testing that this also changes `scrollTo()` calls with `scroll-behavior: 'smooth'` to jump rather than interpolate.

I did an addendum to the question's code example to demo the feature:

```html
<html>
  <button onclick="goToAnchor('b')">Scroll to B</button>
  <p class="reduced-motion">Reduced motion is enabled.</p>
  <div id="a" style="height: 1000px; background-color: blue;">Blue</div>
  <div id="b" style="height: 1000px; background-color: red;">Red</div>
  <div id="c" style="height: 1000px; background-color: green;">Green</div>
</html>
<style>
  .reduced-motion {
    display: none;
  }
  @media (prefers-reduced-motion) {
    .reduced-motion {
      display: inline;
    }
  }
</style>
<script>
  function goToAnchor(anchor) {
    let rect = document.getElementById(anchor).getBoundingClientRect();
    window.scrollTo({
      left: rect.left + window.pageXOffset,
      top: rect.top + window.pageYOffset,
      behavior: 'smooth',
    });
  }
</script>
```

It will now say "Reduced motion is enabled." next to the button depending on your OS and browser configuration. In that case, the scrollTo call will simply jump rather than interpolate.

In short, the issue is that BrowserStack's remote desktop control is also enabling this flag.

Comment: Turning on "Ease of access > Show animations" on windows fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I try to make a test with the **MS Edge Version 87.0.664.60** and **Google Chrome Version 87.0.4280.88**.

On my side, the code works fine on both browsers.

Here is my test result: (Above is the MS Edge and below one is the Google Chrome browser)

[image]

You are making this test using the **BrowserStack**. It is can be possible that the issue is related to **BrowserStack**.

I suggest you try to make a test using the actual browsers. It may help you to find the cause of the issue.

Comment: Yeah, I think you might be right, at least partially. I'm thinking it is related to remote connections in some way. The issue was a finding during feature review by a designer on my current project. It was then brought up to testing by multiple developers, who all reported the same issue - though, it should be noted that I did not have the issue initially when I developed the feature some time ago.

What I now realize is that I were in the office when I developed it initially, but am now connected via RDP along with all other devs. Could this be a Covid-19 related bug? :P